# How to move compressed image file PHP

Tags: php, image-compression

Here is the function that compress image file.

```
function compress_image($source_url, $destination_url, $quality) { 
$info = getimagesize($source_url); 
if ($info['mime'] == 'image/jpeg'){
    $image = imagecreatefromjpeg($source_url); 
}elseif ($info['mime'] == 'image/gif') {
    $image = imagecreatefromgif($source_url); 
}elseif ($info['mime'] == 'image/png') {
    $image = imagecreatefrompng($source_url); 
}imagejpeg($image, $destination_url, $quality); 
return $destination_url; 
} 

$filename = compress_image($_FILES["home_image"]["tmp_name"], $_FILES["home_image"]["name"], 80); 
$buffer = file_get_contents($_FILES["home_image"]["name"]);
```

Here is my code that want to move the compressed image to my specific folder

```
move_uploaded_file($_FILES["home_image"]["tmp_name"][$i],"../../../Test/image/home_banner/" .$filename);
```

But the image that move to the folder is still remain the original size without compress.

Am I doing the mistake..?

Comment: @DanFromGermany As my understanding is the return $destination_url will assign to $filename..correct?
I echo $filename, it show me the image file name.

Answer (score 0):

I think `move_uplodaded_file()` is not appropriate here, because you change the uploaded file contents:

> This function checks to ensure that the file designated by filename is
>   a valid upload file (meaning that it was uploaded via PHP's HTTP POST
>   upload mechanism). If the file is valid, it will be moved to the
>   filename given by destination.

Use `rename()` instead.

I'm also not 100% if you can edit the uploaded file directly..

Comment: is still able to more using rename() but the file size still remain the original size. Can you guild me how to get the compress image file ?